# Occupancy Grid Map generation using ROS

Tags: ros, slam, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to build occupancy grid map in ros using laser data but have no idea from where to start. I dont want to use completely self built package as I am not allowed to use gmapping or hecor. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256813/occupancy-grid-map-generation-using-ros/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me that a good place to start is to look at the occupancy grid map message from the nav_msgs package
http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html

Also look at the laser scan message from sensor_msgs
http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

To visualize it you will probably want to use rviz with the map display type
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Map

Now assuming you have a stream of LaserScan messages you just need to figure out the math to map each ray to a grid cell. To do this you need to know the pose of the laser scanner. You will have to translate the ray direction from the laser scanners coordinate frame to the world coordinate frame. The tf package might help with that http://wiki.ros.org/tf

The hard part will be to handle noise and to properly merge together multiple laser scans over time to get a good probabilistic map.

---

Originally posted by [gudjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/17816/gudjon/) with karma: 111 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Please take a look at how I built an OccupancyGrid from odometry and ultrasonic range data at this repo: https://github.com/RiccardoGiubilato/ros_autonomous_car

---

Originally posted by [RiccardoGiubilato](https://answers.ros.org/users/32342/riccardogiubilato/) with karma: 76 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-10-23**:
thanks. I will have a look :)

**Comment by [MsMimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/34397/msmimi/) on 2019-05-21**:
Hello! Thanks for ur sharing.. may i know what do u mean by pure mapping instead of SLAM in your laser-to-occupancy-grid.py ? Thanks in advance!